# Are women allowed to wear rudrakshas?

Tags: scripture, women, rudraksha

Almost all Sadhus and Sannyasis that we see wear malas made of rudrakshas.I think for them the reasons are spiritual.

But even a common man can wear a rudraksha.For them the reasons can be spiritual or astrological or both.

Rudrakshas can be of various kinds and specific rudrakshas are often worn as [remedies](http://www.astrojyoti.com/mantras2.htm) for specific malefic planets.

For eg-for malefic Sun,1 mukhi or 12 mukhi are recommended,for malefic Moon 2 mukhi ,for malefic Mars 3 mukhi and so on.

[This](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/devibhagvatpurana54.html) Devi Bhagavatam chapter contains a lot about rudrakshas and the benefits of wearing them.

> The origin of Rudrakshas [dark beads of Tree, termed Elaeocorpus
>   Ganitrus in Latin language] or Lord Siva’s tears, extensively used as
>   Prayer Rosaries, goes back to Maha Deva’s killing Tripurasura......

Some restrictions are there .Few are given below:

> All vedic acts are to be accompanied by wearing Rudraksha Malas like
>   Sacrifices, Vraths, Pujas, holy baths, Shraddhas, Solar and Lunar
>   Eclipses, Uttarayana and Dakshinayana ‘Samkramanas’(entry timings),
>   and Full Moon and New Moon days or Pournami and Pradhama days.**However
>   one should not touch or consume wine, meat, tobacco, onion, garlic and
>   such impurities as also during mating, since these constitute
>   atrocious insults to Maha Deva**

**Who can wear them?**

> The white variety of the beads are meant for wearing by Brahmanas, the
>   red colour by Kshatriyas and the black coloured beads by Vaisyas **and
>   others**

But it is not clear to me whether this **others** include women or not.

**Question-Are women allowed to wear rudrakshas?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Women are allowed to wear Rudraksha.

Apart from Devi Bhagavatam, Glory of Rudraksha and prescribed rules are also described in [Rudrakshajabala Upanishad](http://shaivam.org/scripture/English-Translation/1314/rudrakshajabala-upanishat) of Samaveda, [Chapter 25](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-32/topic-1) Vidyesvara Samhita of Shiva Mahapurana besides many other puranas.

Vidyeswara Samhita of Shiva Purana says

> सर्वाश्रमाणां वर्णानां **स्त्री** शूद्राणां शिवाज्ञया। 
>  धार्याः सदैव
> रुद्राक्षा यतीनां प्रणवेन हि॥ ४७॥
>
> People of all the varnas, Asramas, Sudras and the **women**
> should wear Rudraksa at the command of Siva. The ascetics should wear
> it reciting the Omkara mantra.

Parvati Devi Herself wore Rudraksha beads.

Once Goddess Gauri closed eyes of Mahadeva playfully and entire world became dark creating chaos everywhere. Parvati Devi felt bad for Her immature act (as a part of their divine leela) and went to Kanchi and did Tapasya there wearing Rudraksha beads. This is described in [Chapter 4](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-purana/vol-iii/chapter-04/topic-1) Purvaardha - Arunachala Mahatmya of Skanda Mahapurana.

> 10. Setting aside her ornaments of various kinds, she  adorned herself with clusters (i.e. rosaries) of **Rudräksa beads**. Laying aside the
>     divine garments, she wore two auspicious bark garments.

So, women can wear Rudraksha beads.

Comment: Good answer until the end. And where exactly does it say that women should not wear during monthly periods and while performing culinary work??? Or is that your personal superstition?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda This was said by Sri Kakunuri Suryanarayana Murthy in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DjFbEo4z40) (you can watch it if you understand telugu). Just like a Grihastya shouldn't wear them during intercourse, women should avoid them during periods, washing some kind of clothes and while performing some culinary work.  Also, we can observe Parvati Devi wore only during Tapasya. I will update it with authentic scriptures soon.

Comment: @TheDestroyer a video, even of a holy man or a brahmin, is at best only opinion and at worst superstition, and not scripture.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda that "holy man" is well versed in all Sastras. So, not his opinion or Superstition at all.

Comment: @TheDestroyer As an old man I can assure you that I have met many holy men that have used their perceived position to foster their own innate interpretations without scriptural foundation.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda If you do not mind me asking, is Swami an indication that you are a priest? Or is it your name? Or just a username?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I can't understand Telegu, but I would like to know, if you have any ślokas from śāstras which confirm that rudrākṣa can't be worn during intercourse, periods, washing clothes or while performing some culinary work. Could you please help out? As for Vishwananda, he doesn't respect śiṣṭas and Brāhmaṇas, but I don't share his approach.