# Do women face problem in conceiving if she wears rudraksh, does rudraksh has negative effect for women?

Tags: shiva, belief, women, rudraksha

I have bought 2 Mukhi and 9 Mukhi rudraksh recently and I was wearing it. I hadn’t felt any negative effect till now. But one of the priest told me that wearing rudraksh creates problem in pregnancy. Please let me know if women can not wear rudraksh and could there be any problem in pregnancy because of wearing rudraksh?

Comment: Related or possible duplicate of [Are women allowed to wear rudrakshas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16488/3500)

Comment: @kusum There are no negative effects as such provided you wear it as per rituals and with proper guidance, in fact it will have positive effect.